# How to mitigate data loss when converting and manipulating in LAB opponent color space?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, rgb, bgr

I am very new to openCV and learning as I go.

I am using openCV 4.3, however the following is from 2.4:

"If you use cvtColor with 8-bit images, the conversion will have some information lost. For many applications, this will not be noticeable but it is recommended to use 32-bit images in applications that need the full range of colors or that convert an image before an operation and then convert back."

I am using a 24bit jpg image and applying some minor color correction to the LAB channels before converting back to BGR (similar to the warning in the 2.4 notes).

I load the image with:

```
    //Ask user for filename and load with IMREAD_COLOR
    string filename, finalFilename;
    cout << "Which would you like to load? " << "\n";
    cin >> filename;
    cout << "What would you like to call the final image? " << "\n";
    cin >> finalFilename;
    Mat img = imread(filename, IMREAD_COLOR);

    //Convert to CIEL*a*b* format and split for histogram
    Mat imgLab;
    cvtColor(img, imgLab, COLOR_BGR2Lab);


    //Checking type and depth of image to ensure CV_8U (Note: This may have to be converted as to not lose information)
    cout << "IMREAD_COLOR Loaded this image with a depth value of " << img.depth() << " and a type value of " << img.type() << "\n";
    cout << "cvtColor has changed this image to one with a type value of " << imgLab.type() << "\n\n";
```

Then I manipulate the channels later on after assigning them to temp variables:

```
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++)
        {
            modA.at<uint8_t>(i, j) = (float)tempA.at<uint8_t>(i, j) + (0.7f * ((float)mask.at<uint8_t>(i, j))/255 * (128-((float)aBlur.at<uint8_t>(i, j))));
            modB.at<uint8_t>(i, j) = (float)tempB.at<uint8_t>(i, j) + (0.7f * ((float)mask.at<uint8_t>(i, j))/255 * (128-((float)bBlur.at<uint8_t>(i, j))));
        }
    }
```

Mask is a 1 channel 8 bit matrix that holds values from 0-255.
aBlur is tempA with a Gaussian blur applied (same applies to tempB/bBLur).

For some reason, after the conversion, the channels seem to still be skewed from 0-255. (though I could be wrong about this, I noticed that they went above 127 and never below about 100, a bit strange.

I have done a few tests and the type before converting to LAB and after remain the same **(CV_8UC3)**. There is a warning due to the (float) code that there could be information loss:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'float' to '_Tp', possible loss of data OpenCvLearning
```

My question is:
Am I losing information by this process? I noticed my output was not as pleasant as [the paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8901447) I am attempting to reimplement.

Here is the original, my imp, and their result:

[Colours coming out more gray than they should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdfMl.png)

**UPDATE**

So I have updated my code to work with float, which now has many more points possible data (2^32). However when polling the data it is still in 8bit (0-255).

I am attempting to use normalize min n max with the old min and max of the 8bit function and scaling to 0-1 for 32 bit. However, I am concerned about scaling back to 8bit without introducing 8bit error (how can I normalize 0-255 in a matrix that doesn't have 0 or 1 in the 32 bit version?)

Comment: Convert to 32-bit float to do your computations, and don’t convert back to 8-bit unsigned until you’re done and ready to save/display the image.

Comment: Should I do a ".convertTo" and then scale it?